# Regex not matching exact string

Tags: regex, html-parsing

```
Ihrer Bestellung auf Contorion.de verschickt wurde.   Bitte entnehmen Sie genauere Informationen der unten stehenden Auflistung. </p></th><th class="expander" style="padding:0!important;visibility:hidden;width:0"></th></tr></table></th><th class="show-for-large valign-top last columns large-6 small-12" style="Margin:0 auto;margin:0 auto;padding-bottom:0;padding-left:10px;padding-right:0!important;vertical-align:top;width:300px"><table style="border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;display:table;width:100%"><tr><th><table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;display:table;width:100%"><tbody style="display:table;width:100%"><tr><td style="-moz-hyphens:auto;-webkit-hyphens:auto;border-collapse:collapse!important;hyphens:auto;padding:0;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-wrap:break-word"><table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;display:table;width:100%"><tr><td height="20" colspan="3" class="_bt _bl _br" style="-moz-hyphens:auto;-webkit-hyphens:auto;border-collapse:collapse!important;border-left:solid 1px #ccc!important;border-right:solid 1px #ccc!important;border-top:solid 1px #ccc!important;hyphens:auto;padding:0;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-wrap:break-word"></td></tr><tr><td width="20" class="_bl" style="-moz-hyphens:auto;-webkit-hyphens:auto;border-collapse:collapse!important;border-left:solid 1px #ccc!important;hyphens:auto;padding:0;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-wrap:break-word"></td><td style="-moz-hyphens:auto;-webkit-hyphens:auto;border-collapse:collapse!important;hyphens:auto;padding:0;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-wrap:break-word"><p style="Margin:0 0 10px 0;color:#333;font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;font-size:13px;font-weight:400;line-height:1.3;margin:0 0 10px 0;text-align:left"><strong>Bestelldatum:</strong> 19.08.2019<br><strong>Bestellnummer:</strong> <a href="https://www.contorion.de/customer/order-details?order=DE605812349&utm_source=transactional&utm_medium=CRM&utm_campaign=shipping_confirmation" style="Margin:0;color:#60b0ff;font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;font-size:13px;font-weight:400;line-height:1.3;margin:0;text-align:left;text-decoration:none">DE605812349</a><br><strong>Kundennummer:</strong> <a href="https://www.contorion.de/customer/profile?utm_source=transactional&utm_medium=CRM&utm_campaign=shipping_confirmation" style="Margin:0;color:#60b0ff;font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;font-size:13px;font-weight:400;line-height:1.3;margin:0;text-align:left;text-decoration:none">DE2002778724</a><br></p><p style="Margin:0 0 10px 0;color:#333;font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;font-size:13px;font-weight:400;line-height:1.3;margin:0 0 10px 0;text-align:left">Bei Rückfragen bitte Bestellnummer angeben.</p></td><td width="20" class="_br" style="-moz-hyphens:auto;-webkit-hyphens:auto;border-collapse:collapse!important;border-right:solid 1px #ccc!important;hyphens:auto;padding:0;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-wrap:break-word"></td></tr><tr><td height="10" colspan="3" class="_bb _bl _br" style="-moz-hyphens:auto;-webkit-hyphens:auto;border-bottom:solid 1px #ccc!important;border-collapse:collapse!important;border-left:solid 1px #ccc!important;border-right:solid 1px #ccc!important;hyphens:auto;padding:0;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-wrap:break-word"></td></tr></table></td></tr></tbody></table></th><th class="expander" style="padding:0!important;visibility:hidden;width:0"></th></tr></table></th></tr></tbody></table></td></tr></table></td><td width="20" style="-moz-hyphens:auto;-webkit-hyphens:auto;border-collapse:collapse!important;hyphens:auto;padding:0;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-wrap:break-word"></td></tr></table><table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="hide-for-large" style="border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;display:none;font-size:0;height:0;line-height:0;max-height:0;mso-hide:all;overflow:hidden;width:0"><tr style="mso-hide:all"><td style="-moz-hyphens:auto;-webkit-hyphens:auto;border-collapse:collapse!important;hyphens:auto;mso-hide:all;padding:0;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-wrap:break-word"><table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;display:table;mso-hide:all;width:100%"><tr style="mso-hide:all"><td height="20" colspan="3" class="_bt _bl _br" style="-moz-hyphens:auto;-webkit-hyphens:auto;border-collapse:collapse!important;border-left:solid 1px #ccc!important;border-right:solid 1px #ccc!important;border-top:solid 1px #ccc!important;hyphens:auto;mso-hide:all;padding:0;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-wrap:break-word"></td></tr><tr style="mso-hide:all"><td width="20" class="_bl" style="-moz-hyphens:auto;-webkit-hyphens:auto;border-collapse:collapse!important;border-left:solid 1px #ccc!important;hyphens:auto;mso-hide:all;padding:0;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-wrap:break-word"></td><td style="-moz-hyphens:auto;-webkit-hyphens:auto;border-collapse:collapse!important;hyphens:auto;mso-hide:all;padding:0;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-wrap:break-word"><p style="Margin:0 0 10px 0;color:#333;font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;font-size:13px;font-weight:400;line-height:1.3;margin:0 0 10px 0;mso-hide:all;text-align:left"><strong style="mso-hide:all">Bestelldatum:</strong> 19.08.2019<br style="mso-hide:all"><strong style="mso-hide:all">Bestellnummer:</strong> <a href="https://www.contorion.de/customer/order-details?order=DE605812349&utm_source=transactional&utm_medium=CRM&utm_campaign=shipping_confirmation" style="Margin:0;color:#60b0ff;font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;font-size:13px;font-weight:400;line-height:1.3;margin:0;mso-hide:all;text-align:left;text-decoration:none">DE605812349</a><br style="mso-hide:all"><strong style="mso-hide:all">Kundennummer:</strong> <a href="https://www.contorion.de/customer/profile?utm_source=transactional&utm_medium=CRM&utm_campaign=shipping_confirmation" style="Margin:0;color:#60b0ff;font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;font-size:13px;font-weight:400;line-height:1.3;margin:0;mso-hide:all;text-align:left;text-decoration:none">DE2002778724</a><br style="mso-hide:all"></p><p style="Margin:0 0 10px 0;color:#333;font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;font-size:13px;font-weight:400;line-height:1.3;margin:0 0 10px 0;mso-hide:all;text-align:left">Bei Rückfragen bitte Bestellnummer angeben.</p></td><td width="20" class="_br" style="-moz-hyphens:auto;-webkit-hyphens:auto;border-collapse:collapse!important;border-right:solid 1px #ccc!important;hyphens:auto;mso-hide:all;padding:0;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-wrap:break-word"></td></tr><tr style="mso-hide:all"><td height="10" colspan="3" class="_bb _bl _br" style="-moz-hyphens:auto;-webkit-hyphens:auto;border-bottom:solid 1px #ccc!important;border-collapse:collapse!important;border-left:solid 1px #ccc!important;border-right:solid 1px #ccc!important;hyphens:auto;mso-hide:all;padding:0;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-wrap:break-word"></td></tr></table></td></tr><tr style="mso-hide:all"><td height="15" colspan="3" class style="-moz-hyphens:auto;-webkit-hyphens:auto;border-collapse:collapse!important;hyphens:auto;mso-hide:all;padding:0;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-wrap:break-word"></td></tr></table><table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;display:table;width:100%"><tr><td height="15" colspan="3" class="_bb" style="-moz-hyphens:auto;-webkit-hyphens:auto;border-bottom:solid 1px #ccc!important;border-collapse:collapse!important;hyphens:auto;padding:0;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-wrap:break-word"></td></tr><tr><td height="15" colspan="3" class style="-moz-hyphens:auto;-webkit-hyphens:auto;border-collapse:collapse!important;hyphens:auto;padding:0;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-wrap:break-word"></td></tr></table>      <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;display:table;width:100%"><tr><td colspan="3" style="-moz-hyphens:auto;-webkit-hyphens:auto;border-collapse:collapse!important;hyphens:auto;padding:0;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-wrap:break-word"><table class style="border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;display:table;width:100%"><tbody style="display:table;width:100%"><tr><th class="valign-top first columns large-6 small-12" style="Margin:0 auto;margin:0 auto;padding-bottom:0;padding-left:0!important;padding-right:10px;vertical-align:top;width:300px"><table style="border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;display:table;width:100%"><tr><th><table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;display:table;width:100%"><tbody style="display:table;width:100%"><tr><td width="20" style="-moz-hyphens:auto;-webkit-hyphens:auto;border-collapse:collapse!important;hyphens:auto;padding:0;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-wrap:break-word"></td><td style="-moz-hyphens:auto;-webkit-hyphens:auto;border-collapse:collapse!important;hyphens:auto;padding:0;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-wrap:break-word"><table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="button primary" style="border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;display:table;width:100%"><tr><td height="32" width="2" style="-moz-hyphens:auto;-webkit-hyphens:auto;border-collapse:collapse!important;hyphens:auto;padding:0;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-wrap:break-word"><img src="http://media.contorion.de/content/mails/btn/btn_left.png" style="-ms-interpolation-mode:bicubic;clear:both;display:block;float:left;max-width:100%;outline:0;text-decoration:none;width:auto"></td><td height="32" class="valign-middle text-center button__bg" bgcolor="#60b0ff" align="center" style="-moz-hyphens:auto;-webkit-hyphens:auto;background:#60b0ff;border-collapse:collapse!important;color:#fff;hyphens:auto;padding:0;text-align:center;vertical-align:middle;word-wrap:break-word"><table style="border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;display:table;width:100%"><tr><td class="text-center" style="-moz-hyphens:auto;-webkit-hyphens:auto;background:#60b0ff;border-collapse:collapse!important;hyphens:auto;padding:0;text-align:center;vertical-align:top;word-wrap:break-word"><a href="https://gls-group.eu/DE/de/paketverfolgung?match=25147184307&utm_source=transactional&utm_medium=CRM&utm_campaign=shipping_confirmation" style="Margin:0;color:#fff;font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;font-size:13px;font-weight:400;line-height:13px;margin:0;text-align:left;text-decoration:none">Sendung verfolgen</a></td></tr></table></td><td height="32" width="7" class="button__bg button__arrow" bgcolor="#60b0ff" style="-moz-hyphens:auto;-webkit-hyphens:auto;background:#60b0ff;border-collapse:collapse!important;color:#fff;hyphens:auto;padding:0;text-align:left;vertical-align:middle;word-wrap:break-word"><img src="http://media.contorion.de/content/mails/btn/icon_arrow_btn.jpg" style="-ms-interpolation-mode:bicubic;clear:both;display:block;float:left;max-width:100%;outline:0;text-decoration:none;width:auto"></td><td width="10" height="30" class="button__bg" bgcolor="#60b0ff" style="-moz-hyphens:auto;-webkit-hyphens:auto;background:#60b0ff;border-collapse:collapse!important;color:#fff;hyphens:auto;padding:0;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-wrap:break-word"></td><td height="32" width="2" style="-moz-hyphens:auto;-webkit-hyphens:auto;border-collapse:collapse!important;hyphens:auto;padding:0;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-wrap:break-word"><img src="http://media.contorion.de/content/mails/btn/btn_right.png" style="-ms-interpolation-mode:bicubic;clear:both;display:block;float:left;max-width:100%;outline:0;text-decoration:none;width:auto"></td></tr></table></td></tr><tr><td height="15" colspan="2" class style="-moz-hyphens:auto;-webkit-hyphens:auto;border-collapse:collapse!important;hyphens:auto;padding:0;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-wrap:break-word"></td></tr><tr><td width="20" style="-moz-hyphens:auto;-webkit-hyphens:auto;border-collapse:collapse!important;hyphens:auto;padding:0;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-wrap:break-word"></td><td style="-moz-hyphens:auto;-webkit-hyphens:auto;border-collapse:collapse!important;hyphens:auto;padding:0;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-wrap:break-word"><table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;display:table;width:100%"><tbody style="display:table;width:100%"><tr><td style="-moz-hyphens:auto;-webkit-hyphens:auto;border-collapse:collapse!important;hyphens:auto;padding:0;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-wrap:break-word"><p style="Margin:0 0 10px 0;color:#333;font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;font-size:13px;font-weight:400;line-height:1.3;margin:0 0 10px 0;text-align:left"><strong>Rechnungsvermerk:</strong></p></td><td class="hide-for-large" style="-moz-hyphens:auto;-webkit-hyphens:auto;border-collapse:collapse!important;display:none;font-size:0;height:0;hyphens:auto;line-height:0;max-height:0;mso-hide:all;overflow:hidden;padding:0;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;width:0;word-wrap:break-word"><p class="float-right" style="Margin:0 0 10px 0;color:#333;font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;font-size:13px;font-weight:400;line-height:1.3;margin:0 0 10px 0;mso-hide:all;text-align:left">7740/PC-IMT</p></td></tr></tbody></table></td></tr><tr><td height="10" colspan="99" class style="-moz-hyphens:auto;-webkit-hyphens:auto;border-collapse:collapse!important;hyphens:auto;padding:0;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-wrap:break-word"></td></tr><tr class="show-for-large"><td width="20" style="-moz-hyphens:auto;-webkit-hyphens:auto;border-collapse:collapse!important;hyphens:auto;padding:0;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-wrap:break-word"></td><td style="-moz-hyphens:auto;-webkit-hyphens:auto;border-collapse:collapse!important;hyphens:auto;padding:0;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-wrap:break-word"><p style="Margin:0 0 10px 0;color:#333;font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;font-size:13px;font-weight:400;line-height:1.3;margin:0 0 10px 0;text-align:left">7740/PC-IMT</p></td></tr><tr><td height="15" colspan="99" class style="-moz-hyphens:auto;-webkit-hyphens:auto;border-collapse:collapse!important;hyphens:auto;padding:0;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-wrap:break-word"></td></tr></tbody></table></th><th class="expander" style="padding:0!important;visibility:hidden;width:0"></th></tr></table></th><th class="valign-top columns large-6 small-12" style="Margin:0 auto;margin:0 auto;padding-bottom:0;padding-left:10px;padding-right:10px;vertical-align:top;width:300px"><table style="border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;display:table;width:100%"><tr><th><table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;display:table;width:100%"><tbody style="display:table;width:100%"><tr><td width="20" style="-moz-hyphens:auto;-webkit-hyphens:auto;border-collapse:collapse!important;hyphens:auto;padding:0;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-wrap:break-word"></td><td style="-moz-hyphens:auto;-webkit-hyphens:auto;border-collapse:collapse!important;hyphens:auto;padding:0;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-wrap:break-word"><table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;display:table;width:100%"><tbody style="display:table;width:100%"><tr><td class="valign-middle" style="-moz-hyphens:auto;-webkit-hyphens:auto;border-collapse:collapse!important;hyphens:auto;padding:0;text-align:left;vertical-align:middle;word-wrap:break-word"><p style="Margin:0 0 10px 0;color:#333;font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;font-size:13px;font-weight:400;line-height:1.3;margin:0 0 10px 0;text-align:left"><strong>Versendet mit</strong></p></td><td class="hide-for-large" style="-moz-hyphens:auto;-webkit-hyphens:auto;border-collapse:collapse!important;display:none;font-size:0;height:0;hyphens:auto;line-height:0;max-height:0;mso-hide:all;overflow:hidden;padding:0;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;width:0;word-wrap:break-word"><img width="56" height="30" class="float-right" src="https://media.contorion.de/content/mails/order/GLS.jpg" style="-ms-interpolation-mode:bicubic;clear:both;display:block;float:right;max-width:100%;mso-hide:all;outline:0;text-align:right;text-decoration:none;width:auto"></td></tr></tbody></table></td></tr><tr class="show-for-large"><td width="20" style="-moz-hyphens:auto;-webkit-hyphens:auto;border-collapse:collapse!important;hyphens:auto;padding:0;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-wrap:break-word"></td><td style="-moz-hyphens:auto;-webkit-hyphens:auto;border-collapse:collapse!important;hyphens:auto;padding:0;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-wrap:break-word"><img width="56" height="30" src="https://media.contorion.de/content/mails/order/GLS.jpg" style="-ms-interpolation-mode:bicubic;clear:both;display:block;max-width:100%;outline:0;text-decoration:none;width:auto"></td></tr> <tr><td height="15" colspan="2" class style="-moz-hyphens:auto;-webkit-hyphens:auto;border-collapse:collapse!important;hyphens:auto;padding:0;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-wrap:break-word"></td></tr><tr><td width="20" style="-moz-hyphens:auto;-webkit-hyphens:auto;border-collapse:collapse!important;hyphens:auto;padding:0;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-wrap:break-word"></td><td style="-moz-hyphens:auto;-webkit-hyphens:auto;border-collapse:collapse!important;hyphens:auto;padding:0;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-wrap:break-word"><table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;display:table;width:100%"><tbody style="display:table;width:100%"><tr><td style="-moz-hyphens:auto;-webkit-hyphens:auto;border-collapse:collapse!important;hyphens:auto;padding:0;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-wrap:break-word"><p style="Margin:0 0 10px 0;color:#333;font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;font-size:13px;font-weight:400;line-height:1.3;margin:0 0 10px 0;text-align:left"><strong>Sendungsnr.</strong></p></td><td class="hide-for-large" style="-moz-hyphens:auto;-webkit-hyphens:auto;border-collapse:collapse!important;display:none;font-size:0;height:0;hyphens:auto;line-height:0;max-height:0;mso-hide:all;overflow:hidden;padding:0;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;width:0;word-wrap:break-word"><p class="float-right" style="Margin:0 0 10px 0;color:#333;font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;font-size:13px;font-weight:400;line-height:1.3;margin:0 0 10px 0;mso-hide:all;text-align:left">25147184307</p></td></tr></tbody></table></td></tr><tr><td height="10" colspan="99" class style="-moz-hyphens:auto;-webkit-hyphens:auto;border-collapse:collapse!important;hyphens:auto;padding:0;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-wrap:break-word"></td></tr><tr class="show-for-large"><td width="20" style="-moz-hyphens:auto;-webkit-hyphens:auto;border-collapse:collapse!important;hyphens:auto;padding:0;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-wrap:break-word"></td><td style="-moz-hyphens:auto;-webkit-hyphens:auto;border-collapse:collapse!important;hyphens:auto;padding:0;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-wrap:break-word"><p style="Margin:0 0 10px 0;color:#333;font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;font-size:13px;font-weight:400;line-height:1.3;margin:0 0 10px 0;text-align:left">25147184307</p></td></tr></tbody></table></th><th class="expander" style="padding:0!important;visibility:hidden;width:0"></th></tr></table></th><th class="valign-top last columns large-6 small-12" style="Margin:0 auto;margin:0 auto;padding-bottom:0;padding-left:10px;padding-right:0!important;vertical-align:top;width:300px"><table style="border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;display:table;width:100%"><tr><th><table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;display:table;width:100%"><tr><td width="20" style="-moz-hyphens:auto;-webkit-hyphens:auto;border-collapse:collapse!important;hyphens:auto;padding:0;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-wrap:break-word"></td><td style="-moz-hyphens:auto;-webkit-hyphens:auto;border-collapse:collapse!important;hyphens:auto;padding:0;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-wrap:break-word"><table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;display:table;width:100%"><tr><td style="-moz-hyphens:auto;-webkit-hyphens:auto;border-collapse:collapse!important;hyphens:auto;padding:0;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-wrap:break-word"><p style="Margin:0 0 10px 0;color:#333;font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;font-size:13px;font-weight:400;line-height:1.3;margin:0 0 10px 0;text-align:left"><strong>Lieferadresse</strong></p></td></tr><tr><td height="5" colspan="1" class style="-moz-hyphens:auto;-webkit-hyphens:auto;border-collapse:collapse!important;hyphens:auto;padding:0;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-wrap:break-word"></td></tr><tr><td style="-moz-hyphens:auto;-webkit-hyphens:auto;border-collapse:collapse!important;hyphens:auto;padding:0;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-wrap:break-word"><p style="Margin:0 0 10px 0;color:#333;font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;font-size:13px;font-weight:400;line-height:1.3;margin:0 0 10px 0;text-align:left">Böllhoff Produktion GmbH<br> Product Center Injection Moulding  Technology  (PC IMT)<br>Sachbearbeitung Materialwirtschaft<br> Archimedesstr. 1-4 <br>33649 Bielefeld</p></td></tr></table></td><td width="20" style="-moz-hyphens:auto;-webkit-hyphens:auto;border-collapse:collapse!important;hyphens:auto;padding:0;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-wrap:break-word"></td></tr></table></th><th class="expander" style="padding:0!important;visibility:hidden;width:0"></th></tr></table></th></tr></tbody></table></td><td width="20" style="-moz-hyphens:auto;-webkit-hyphens:auto;border-collapse:collapse!important;hyphens:auto;padding:0;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-wrap:break-word"></td></tr></table><table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;display:table;width:100%"><tbody style="display:table;width:100%"><tr><td height="15" colspan="3" class="_bb" style="-moz-hyphens:auto;-webkit-hyphens:auto;border-bottom:solid 1px #ccc!important;border-collapse:collapse!important;hyphens:auto;padding:0;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-wrap:break-word"></td></tr><tr><td height="15" colspan="3" class style="-moz-hyphens:auto;-webkit-hyphens:auto;border-collapse:collapse!important;hyphens:auto;padding:0;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-wrap:break-word"></td></tr></tbody></table><table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="container" style="Margin:0!important;border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;display:table;margin:0!important;text-align:inherit;width:640px"><tr><td width="20" style="-moz-hyphens:auto;-webkit-hyphens:auto;border-collapse:collapse!important;hyphens:auto;padding:0;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-wrap:break-word"></td><td style="-moz-hyphens:auto;-webkit-hyphens:auto;border-collapse:collapse!important;hyphens:auto;padding:0;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-wrap:break-word"><table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;display:table;width:100%"><tr><td width="23" style="-moz-hyphens:auto;-webkit-hyphens:auto;border-collapse:collapse!important;hyphens:auto;padding:0;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-wrap:break-word"><img width="23" height="23" src="https://media.contorion.de/content/mails/order/info-icon.png" style="-ms-interpolation-mode:bicubic;clear:both;display:block;max-width:100%;outline:0;text-decoration:none;width:auto"></td><td width="10" style="-moz-hyphens:auto;-webkit-hyphens:auto;border-collapse:collapse!important;hyphens:auto;padding:0;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-wrap:break-word"></td><td style="-moz-hyphens:auto;-webkit-hyphens:auto;border-collapse:collapse!important;hyphens:auto;padding:0;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-wrap:break-word"><p style="Margin:0 0 10px 0;color:#333;font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;font-size:13px;font-weight:400;line-height:1.3;margin:0 0 10px 0;text-align:left"> Die Sendung wurde mit GLS Paket versandt.   Wenn Sie diese Sendung verfolgen möchten, benutzen Sie bitte diese Paketverfolgungsnummer: 25147184307.  Diese Mail bestätigt, dass Ihr Paket an den Pakendienstleister übergeben wurde. Nach der Übergabe kann es bis zu 12 Stunden dauern, bis das Paket im Paketzentrum gescannt wird und weitere Informationen zur Sendungsverfolgung über obigen Link abrufbar sind.</p></td></tr></table></td><td width="20" style="-moz-hyphens:auto;-webkit-hyphens:auto;border-collapse:collapse!important;hyphens:auto;padding:0;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-wrap:break-word"></td></tr><tr><td height="20" colspan="99" class style="-moz-hyphens:auto;-webkit-hyphens:auto;border-collapse:collapse!important;hyphens:auto;padding:0;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-wrap:break-word"></td></tr> <!-- Shipments --><tr><td colspan="3" style="-moz-hyphens:auto;-webkit-hyphens:auto;border-collapse:collapse!important;hyphens:auto;padding:0;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-wrap:break-word"><table class="_bt _br _bl" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse:collapse;border-left:solid 1px #ccc!important;border-right:solid 1px #ccc!important;border-spacing:0;border-top:solid 1px #ccc!important;display:table;width:100%"><tr><td height="15" colspan="3" class="bg-gray" style="-moz-hyphens:auto;-webkit-hyphens:auto;background:#f3f3f3;border-collapse:collapse!important;hyphens:auto;padding:0;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-wrap:break-word"></td></tr><tr><td class="bg-gray" width="20" style="-moz-hyphens:auto;-webkit-hyphens:auto;background:#f3f3f3;border-collapse:collapse!important;hyphens:auto;padding:0;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-wrap:break-word"></td><td class="bg-gray" style="-moz-hyphens:auto;-webkit-hyphens:auto;background:#f3f3f3;border-collapse:collapse!important;hyphens:auto;padding:0;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-wrap:break-word"><p class="nomargin" style="Margin:0!important;color:#333;font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;font-size:13px;font-weight:400;line-height:1.3;margin:0!important;margin-bottom:0!important;margin-top:0!important;text-align:left"><strong>Ihre Teillieferung</strong></p></td><td class="bg-gray" width="20" style="-moz-hyphens:auto;-webkit-hyphens:auto;background:#f3f3f3;border-collapse:collapse!important;hyphens:auto;padding:0;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-wrap:break-word"></td></tr><tr><td height="15" colspan="3" class="bg-gray" style="-moz-hyphens:auto;-webkit-hyphens:auto;background:#f3f3f3;border-collapse:collapse!important;hyphens:auto;padding:0;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-wrap:break-word"></td></tr><tr><td height="15" colspan="3" class style="-moz-hyphens:auto;-webkit-hyphens:auto;border-collapse:collapse!important;hyphens:auto;padding:0;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-wrap:break-word"></td></tr><tr><td colspan="3" style="-moz-hyphens:auto;-webkit-hyphens:auto;border-collapse:collapse!important;hyphens:auto;padding:0;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-wrap:break-word"><table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;display:table;width:100%"><tbody style="display:table;width:100%"><tr><td width="20" style="-moz-hyphens:auto;-webkit-hyphens:auto;border-collapse:collapse!important;hyphens:auto;padding:0;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-wrap:break-word"></td><td width="70" style="-moz-hyphens:auto;-webkit-hyphens:auto;border-collapse:collapse!important;hyphens:auto;padding:0;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-wrap:break-word"><img width="42" height="42" src="http://media.contorion.de/media/images/products/din-1440-flache-scheibe-edelstahl-a4-12mm-produktklasse-a-91368379-0-rGZGVmCY-s.jpg" style="-ms-interpolation-mode:bicubic;clear:both;display:block;max-width:100%;outline:0;text-decoration:none;width:auto"></td><td width="10" style="-moz-hyphens:auto;-webkit-hyphens:auto;border-collapse:collapse!important;hyphens:auto;padding:0;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-wrap:break-word"></td><td style="-moz-hyphens:auto;-webkit-hyphens:auto;border-collapse:collapse!important;hyphens:auto;padding:0;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-wrap:break-word"><p style="Margin:0 0 10px 0;color:#333;font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;font-size:13px;font-weight:400;line-height:1.3;margin:0 0 10px 0;text-align:left"><strong>DIN 1440 Flache Scheibe Edelstahl A4 12mm Produktklasse A</strong></p></td><td width="10" class="show-for-large" font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;font-size:13px;font-weight:400;line-height:1.3;margin:0 0 10px 0;text-align:left"><strong>DIN 316 Flügelschraube amerikansiche Form M10x50 Edelstahl A2 blank</strong></p></td><td width="10" class="show-for-large" style="-moz-hyphens:auto;-webkit-hyphens:auto;border-collapse:collapse!importantA233hov39YG3zxPW4unCSHAcWReP8A2hzLqM"></body></html>
```

I have this HTML where I am meant to match the articles/product items.

Here is the regex: `<strong>(.*?)<\/strong><\/p><\/td><td width="10"`

The second article matches perfectly, but the first one is matching too much and I need an exact match. `<\/p><\/td><td width="10"` should come exactly after </strong> but it is matching it way down the page.

I've tried using ^...$ but it isn't working for some reason..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is slow, but instead of matching everything inside the tag as you currently do `.*?`, you could insert a [negative lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) `(?!<strong>)` and match everything `.` except for characters followed by the opening tag you want to avoid, here `<strong>`

```regex
<strong>((.(?!<strong>))*?)<\/strong><\/p><\/td><td width="10"
```

this prevents the regex from matching any additional `<strong>` tags after the first matched one

if you want to prevent creating an additional group from the newly added parenthesis, you can make the inner part [non-capturing](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html)

```regex
((?:.(?!<strong>))*?)
```